# How can I change the position of the input cursor in text fields to be right justified for arabic text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Arabic writing starts from right to left but the blinking cursor is on the left side. is there a way to program it or configure it to be positioned on the right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

or use the css attribute direction

```
direction: rtl;
```

Answer (score 2):

just use css;

```
input.arabic { text-align:right; }
<input type="text" class="arabic" />
```

although this does not make the newest inserted character appear to the left of the last one... To do this you should write an invert function and use javascript (or jquery). It would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var reverseFunc = function() {
            $('input').each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass('arabic')) {
                    // do the invert magic...
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    var newVal = val.charAt(val.length-1) + substr(0, val.length-1);
                    $(this).val(val);
                }
            });
        }

        $('input').bind('keyup', reverseFunc);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why do this when all browsers do support 'right-to-left' languages, just using the `direction:rtl` will do.

Comment: yeah, you're quite right... didn't think of that ;) but it was a good practice :p

Answer (score 1):

In input box the for cursor to start from right hand side just apply any one of the css property below

```
input {
    text-align: right
}
```

or

```
input {
    text-align: end
}
```

or

```
input {
    direction: rtl; // or dir attribute is rtl in input tag
    text-align: start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

For Asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="rightAlignText"></asp:TextBox>
```

For html only:

```
<input id="txt" class="rightAlignText">
```

and add this in your css file.

```
.rightAlignText
{
   text-align:right;
   cursor: text;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my web development in different languages. You only have to worry about the ISO language, so it does not show the "?" at unrecognized characters and the orientation of the texts (RTL - LTR) to facilitate the readability of the information published. The rest is the locale of the keyboard web user.

If the locale is Arabic (or any other language of similar orientation, eg Hebrew), the input text is written from right to left, the delete and delete keys will be invested and the cursor will be placed at the end of text.